# updateLong not allowed in ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset, derby

I am trying to add a serial number in my table. Here is my method:

```
public void reArrangeTrID(){
String parti = name.getText().toUpperCase();    
long trid = 1;

try{
String query="SELECT LONGDATE, TRID FROM PARTIACCOUNT WHERE PARTY= '"+parti+"' ORDER BY LONGDATE ASC ";
conn = new connection().db();
stmtt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
rs = stmtt.executeQuery(query);
while(rs.next()) {
    long tr = rs.getLong("TRID");
    rs.updateLong("TRID", trid);
    rs.updateRow();
    trid++;
    jLabel9.setText("Arranging transactions... Please wait.");
}
 }

catch (SQLException ex) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unknown Error!! Data cannot be displayed!"+ex);
}
finally{try{stmtt.close(); rs.close(); conn.close(); }catch(SQLException ex){}}
}
```

Why this method gives me an error that `updateLong not allowed because ResultSet is not an updatable ResultSet`, while my resultset is already set to updatable.
I am using derby database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Derby Documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/rrefsqlj41360.html#rrefsqlj41360__sqlj15384), a query with an `ORDER BY` is not updatable:

> Only simple, single-table SELECT cursors can be updatable. The SELECT statement for updatable ResultSets has the same syntax as the SELECT statement for updatable cursors. To generate updatable cursors:
>
> - **The `SELECT` statement must not include an `ORDER BY` clause.**
> - The underlying Query must be a SelectExpression.
> - The SelectExpression in the underlying Query must not include:
>
>   - `DISTINCT`
>   - Aggregates
>   - `GROUP BY` clause
>   - `HAVING` clause
>   - `ORDER BY` clause
> - The `FROM` clause in the underlying Query must not have:
>
>   - more than one table in its `FROM` clause
>   - anything other than one table name
>   - SelectExpressions
>   - subqueries
> - If the underlying Query has a `WHERE` clause, the `WHERE` clause must not have subqueries.

In other words you can't include the `ORDER BY`, but that would defeat your purpose (as you seem to be renumbering some identifier).

You either need to use some query to renumber without processing in JDBC, or you need to use two `Statement` objects, one to query the rows and another to update them.

---

Derby also [does not support `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/devguide/cdevconcepts22641.html) result sets. According to the documentation, Derby supports both:

- [`TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/devguide/rdevconceptsfor.html) and
- [`TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/devguide/rdevconceptssur.html)

Note that your current code doesn't require `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` because you are only processing it as a forward only.

Comment: It's useful. I'd have to write two queries, as I must use 'ORDER BY'.

Answer (score 2):

As per [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE)

```
static final int TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE
```

The constant indicating the type for a ResultSet object that is scrollable and **generally sensitive to changes to the data that underlies the ResultSet**.

What you are looking for might be:

```
static final int TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE
```

The constant indicating the type for a ResultSet object that is **scrollable but generally not sensitive to changes to the data that underlies the ResultSet**.

Comment: Sorry. But no effect.

Comment: @PranjalCholadhara: Please explain "But no effect". Update full exception stack.

Comment: @PranjalCholadhara: And this may help you (If you haven't already refer) http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/cdevconcepts28351.html

Comment: I changed it to 'TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE'. But I get the same message. If I remove 'ORDER BY' from the query, it works fine. But I cannot remove the 'ORDER BY' to fulfill my logic.

Comment: @PranjalCholadhara: Please refer above link and "For update" clause in derby manual. It seems there are certain restricitons.

Comment: The sensitivity has to do with detecting updates, not with the updatability.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: can you elaborate your comment little bit more? Curious to know the difference.

Comment: `SCROLL_SENSITIVE` means that the result set detects that changes were made by others(!) in the database (eg in a read committed connection, when another user commits their changes).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: You mean, updates to underlying data by others, not from same resultset? As per doc, it is just saying updates to underlying data, not restricting that updates should be from others (not same resultset), isn't it? and what do you suggest for OP problem (I see that you have developed jdbc drivers, so expertise might help)

Comment: Result set type does not decide if a resultset is updatable, only concurrency does (although a driver might not support certain combinations of type and concurrency). The JDBC specification itself says "The result set reflects changes made to the underlying data source". And the data source is the actual database, unfortunately for some things in the JDBC spec you need to read between the lines (for example, `DatabaseMetaData` has methods like `othersUpdatesAreVisible` and `ownUpdatesAreVisible`) which seems to imply more subtleties than in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your particular flavor of SQL is, but how about doing it in a single update statements instead of a read+update, something like this:

```
UPDATE Sometable
SET col1 =
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Sometable AS S
WHERE keycol <= Sometable.keycol)
```

Comment: But my serial number should always be according to date.